# I need to generate 1000 unique first name In Python

Tags: python

I need to generate 1000 unique first names and store them in a list.
I am using Python faker but getting so many repeated values.

```
import random
from random import shuffle
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()
fake.random.seed(4321)  

first_n=[]
for i in range(1000):
    name=fake.first_name()
    if name in first_n:
        first_n.append("Repeat")
    else:
        first_n.append(name)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of generating random values and then checking if they're unique, retrieve the list of the names stored in the provider you're using, shuffle them and return the first 1000. That way you won't run into collisions at all. There's about 7k first names defined in the `en` provider, while the other languages may have far less - making collisions rather certain as you're getting further into the sequence.

```
from random import shuffle, seed
from faker.providers.person.en import Provider

first_names = list(set(Provider.first_names))

seed(4321)
shuffle(first_names)

print(first_names[0:1000])
```

Comment: Thanks,
But every time I am getting different values. I need the same values on every run.

Comment: In that case seed the random number generator before calling shuffle with the same seed each time as in your own example. I've updated the code in my answer to use seed as well.

Comment: from random import shuffle, seed
from faker.providers.person.en import Provider

first_names = list(Provider.first_names)

seed(4321)
shuffle(first_names)

li=(first_names[0:1000])
print(len(li))

new=[]
for n in li:
    if n in new:
        new.append("repeat")
    else:
        new.append(n)
        
print(sorted(new))

Getting the Repeated value at last of the list.
"'Zoey', 'Zollie', 'Zora', 'repeat', 'repeat', 'repeat', 'repeat', 'repeat']"

Comment: Ah, that can be caused by there being duplicates across male and female names. You can create a set before extracting the unique names as a list. I've updated the code again.

Comment: Can I use the same for Last_name?

Comment: Should work; check the Provider class you're using on github to see exactly what is available.

Answer (score 7):

Since version [4.9.0](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#490---2020-10-08), python's Faker library has built-in functionality for supporting unique values.
See the [relevant section of the README](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#490---2020-10-08).

In essence, one can now do:

```py
from faker import Faker
faker = Faker()
names = [faker.unique.first_name() for _ in range(500)]
assert len(set(names)) == len(names)
```

Answer (score 3):

Youll want to store data in a set instead of a list to prevent duplicates

Then you can use a while loop

```
first_n = set()
while len(first_n) < 1000:
    first_n.add(fake.first_name())
```

Comment: I am getting error..
"AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: should be add instead of append. But it maybe slow.

Comment: @Abhi It should. As mentioned, it'll be slow, though

Comment: Yeah, It's too slow, still not getting the result.
Any other option??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set, and keep adding until the length is what you desire:

```
names = set()
while len(names) < LENGTH:
    names.add(NAME)
```

You can then convert back to a list:

```
names = list(names)
```