# Unique list with objects

Tags: python, faker

I have simple list:

```
simple_list = [
   SimpleObject(name=faker.name(), city=faker.city())
   for i in range(0, 10)
]
```

This gives me for example:

```
simple_list = [
   SimpleObject(name="aaa", city="London"),
   SimpleObject(name="bbb", city="Madrid"),
   SimpleObject(name="ccc", city="Paris"),
   SimpleObject(name="ddd", city="Madrid"),
]
```

How to ensure the uniqueness of this list using the city key? In my example, I would like to receive:

```
simple_list = [
   SimpleObject(name="aaa", city="London"),
   SimpleObject(name="bbb", city="Madrid"),
   SimpleObject(name="ccc", city="Paris"),
]
```

or

```
simple_list = [
   SimpleObject(name="aaa", city="London"),
   SimpleObject(name="ccc", city="Paris"),
   SimpleObject(name="ddd", city="Madrid"),
]
```

It doesn't matter to me which ones, it's important that the cities don't repeat themselves.

Comment: @Mark - The `faker` tag wasn't added by the OP, even though the OP is using faker in this [mcve], that doesn't necesarily mean the actual code does. The op's question is above making a list unique based off an attribute of the elements.

Comment: Yes @Sayse, but the correct answer is below for this question. That answer will never appear on the dupe you mentioned. This question and the answer below provides unique value to future users.

Comment: OP, are you asking how to make unique values with faker, or to make a unique list?

Comment: @Mark - I agree that the below answer is a good answer if thats what is being asked, but that is still different to what is written

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the OP intends or who added the `faker` tag. What matters is that this is valuable to future users. Perhaps asking the OP to clarify in the title will improve it even more for the future.

Comment: @Mark - Well then theres the [existing duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836752/i-need-to-generate-1000-unique-first-name-in-python/55836950) to what is proposed as the real question here where the accepted answer is to use a [provider](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.address.html#faker.providers.address.Provider.city) (or unique as a seperate answer). Its not up to us to change the OP's original question into one that provides value

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a `Faker` instance with the `unique` attribute:

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

simple_list = [
   SimpleObject(name=fake.name(), city=fake.unique.city())
   for i in range(0, 10)
]
```

Note that Faker will raise an exception if it can't find a new unique value. From the docs:

> Note, to avoid infinite loops, after a number of attempts to find a unique value, Faker will throw a UniquenessException. Beware of the birthday paradox, collisions are more likely than you’d think.

https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/#unique-values